# iOS 5 and facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, authentication, sdk, ios5

I'm using the official facebook SDK for iOS, and the iOS 5 SDK.
I read the official guide on the facebook developer website and I happily get my friends list from facebbok.
Now, in a "real" application I (and practically everybody) need to perform requests to facebook from several controllers using the same instance of the facebook connection.
In order to do that, I wrapped the facebook instance in a singletone class and I'm going to get the responses to facebook requests using a shared object of this class in many controllers.
In this way, the method fbDidLogin is never called, neither the method fbDidNotLogin.

I don't know if it is the proper way, if there is a better way, please let me know.